# Output Select-String Context all Line Values

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0, powershell-ise

I'm doing Select-String to find a pattern in a bunch of .dco's
and using this line I get:

```
PS C:\> gci $folder -filter *.dco -Recurse | Select-String -Pattern $pattern 

C:\path\path\23_DCO\2017\12 December\DCO_CYC15_E_15122017.DCO:373:MTR150000010010          0  0RA              409347    0100000125000001250000140000NN  NNE 000
```

The pattern matches, and I get that line. The line with the actual data I need is underneath it though, so I add the parameter -Context

```
PS C:\> gci $folder -filter *.dco -Recurse | Select-String -Pattern $pattern -Context 1

  C:\path\path\23_DCO\2017\12 December\DCO_CYC15_E_15122017.DCO:372:CUS150000010010001288502                                     
> C:\path\path\23_DCO\2017\12 December\DCO_CYC15_E_15122017.DCO:373:MTR150000010010          0  0RA              409347    0100000125000001250000140000NN  NNE 000                            
  C:\path\path\23_DCO\2017\12 December\DCO_CYC15_E_15122017.DCO:374:RDG15000001KH01R000000000K00000100000000271000012152017000000N000000000000UMETERSENS000000000K 10000000000000000267
```

It is the 3rd line with the value I care about, but all 3 lines of information is useful, so I wish to export this.

This line of code gives me  the data exactly how I want it outputted:

```
$Found | Select * -ExcludeProperty RowError, RowState, HasErrors, Table, ItemArray, IgnoreCase, Context | Export-Excel

LineNumber : 373
Line       : MTR150000010010          0  0RA              409347    0100000125000001250000140000NN  NNE 000                            
Filename   : DCO_CYC15_E_15112017_2.DCO
Path       : P:\path\path\23_DCO\2017\11 November\DCO_CYC15_E_15112017_2.DCO
Pattern    : 409347
Matches    : {0}
```

However, that is only the matched line in the "Line:" property.
How do I include the two other lines from -Context?

If that is not possible, I'm happy with this line, the 3rd line from the -Context 1 output:

```
 RDG15000001KH01R000000000K00000100000000271000012152017000000N000000000000UMETERSENS000000000K 10000000000000000267
```

How could I switch that as the line data included in the Export if I cannot get all 3 lines?

**Note:**
This is all done in a loop. In this case, there is only 1 match, but there can be several.

```
$Found = @()
Foreach ($folder in $folders)
{
    $Found += gci $folder -filter *.dco -Recurse | Select-String -Pattern $pattern -Context 1 
    if ($Found) {
        $Found | Select * -ExcludeProperty RowError, RowState, HasErrors, Table, ItemArray, IgnoreCase, Context | Export-Excel -Path $savepathr -WorkSheetname "$pattern" -AutoSize -BoldTopRow -FreezeTopRow
        $row.Status = "Found in File"
    }
}
```

Thanks, hope you understand what I am asking.

Comment: The `Context` properties are arrays.  You assign the match to a variable and access them.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 how can I output them neatly to that excel file together though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a calculated property to grab the 3rd line from the `Context` property:

```
$Found | Select *,@{Name='PostContext';Expression={$_.Context.PostContext}} -ExcludeProperty RowError, RowState, HasErrors, Table, ItemArray, IgnoreCase, Context | Export-Excel -Path $savepathr -WorkSheetname "$pattern" -AutoSize -BoldTopRow -FreezeTopRow
```

Your current loop will result in duplicates due to the `$Found += ...` statement followed by exporting all found instances captured so far.

```
$Found = foreach ($folder in $folders) {
    Get-ChildItem $folder -Filter *.dco -Recurse | Select-String -Pattern $pattern -Context 1 
}
if ($Found) {
    $Found | Select *,@{Name='PostContext';Expression={$_.Context.PostContext}} -ExcludeProperty RowError, RowState, HasErrors, Table, ItemArray, IgnoreCase, Context | Export-Excel -Path $savepathr -WorkSheetname "$pattern" -AutoSize -BoldTopRow -FreezeTopRow
    $row.Status = "Found in File"
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is exactly what I needed.